Old cartoon about a man living on a spacestation
I remember watching an old cartoon about 10-15 years ago. A man was living on a space station with his family. The space-station looks like a normal neighborhood except that they have some kind of glass sky. I remember the man controlling the weather (maybe other things too) to make it seem Earth like. I think there is a house with his family, a house for his mother and I remember another house with some Russian guy.
I think the station looked somewhat like this:


Was there a robot maid and a dog aswell perhaps?

@Decypher it's not the Jetsons if you think about them.

I think this may have been a French-Canadian animation called Spaced Out.
The Russian Guy was named Boris something russian
I may be wrong, I only ever caught maybe three episodes.

Yup, you are right. Thank you :)
